# connection button not working

Tags: java, swing, connection, chat, event-dispatch-thread

Whenever I click the event button the program becomes unresponsive Is there something wrong with my code?

```
void btnConnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){

    try{
        btnSend.setEnabled(true);
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4446);
        Scanner serverType = new Scanner(chatTxt.getText());
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


    }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Use a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: This line `Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();` is the ROOT of the cause, such calls are never done on the `EDT- Event Dispatch Thread`,  start a new thread for this and always update your GUI on the `EDT`. Now until and unless, someone won't connect to this `Socket` your GUI will not response, that's why this line is the road to ____________ !!!! Fill the blank as you like :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nothing wrong with the code, except you executing a time consuming task within the `Event Dispatching Thread`.

This will prevent the UI from been updated as the `EDT` is responsible for processing paint updates as well as handling keyboard and mouse event processing.

As already suggested, check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Just a side note for **"EDT is responsible for processing paint updates as well as handling keyboard and mouse event processing"**. Here IMHO, EDT is not responsible for such things (leave the paint updates), that task belongs to the toolkit thread, which is responsible for capturing system events like as you mentioned in that line, though this thread never runs Application Code now Captured Events are send over to EDT from this toolkit thread :-) Did upvoted this answer though a bit earlier, just now I went a bit deep to notice this thingy :-)

Comment: Okay, more precisely, the EDT dispatches the key/mouse events ;)